# How do i convert this bitmap image into uri in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, uri

here's the code to convert `Uri` into `Bitmap`

```
imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), galleryImage);
```

i want to convert this bitmap image into uri to view it on `ImageView` :

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap cameraBitmapImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
Uri cameraImage = data.getData();
imageView.setImageURI(cameraImage);
isImageSelected = true;
imageBitmap = cameraBitmapImage;
```

Comment: To view a `bitmap` in an `ImageView`, just call `ImageView#setImageBitmap`. There is no need to conver the image to a `Uri`. Though this is not answering your question so just treat me as an advice here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945443/7874746

Comment: One cannot convert an uri in a bitmap. Or a bitmap in an uri. They are quite incomparable.

Comment: You can save the bitmap as file in local storage then you will get the Uri of that file.